# Find non-consecutive combinations of words in a string from array of words using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a way to return the start position and matched pattern from a string of (possibly) non consecutive matching patterns of any combination of `$search` in `$pattern` of `$length`.

In my example, looking for phone numbers where digits are words.

```
$subject = "hello my name is inigo montoya you killed my father please call me at eight zero zero five five five one to three four prepare to die"

$search = array("zero", "one", "two", "to", "too" "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine")

$length = 10;

$result = jedi_find_trick($subject,$search,$length);
```

Would set `$result` to an array:

```
$result[0]["start"] = 70
$result[0]["match"] = "eight zero zero five five five one to three four"
$result[1] ...
```

Generating all possible combinations of `$search` is where I'm headed but I feel like there is a much more elegant solution escaping me, thanks for any suggestions.

---

Based on @chris85's suggestion, this seems to be a great starting point:

```
$subject = 'hello my name is inigo montoya you killed my father please call me at eight zero zero five five five one to three four or too oh five seven seven seven five one one one prepare to die';
$search = array('zero','oh','one','two','too','to','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','hundred','thousand');
$replace = array('0','0','1','2','2','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','00','000');
$length = 10;

$result = jedi_find_trick($subject,$search,$replace,10);

$result = jedi_find_trick($subject,$search,$replace,$length);

print_r($result);

function jedi_find_trick($subject,$search,$replace,$length) {

    preg_match_all('/(\h*(' . implode('|', $search) . ')\h*){10}/', $subject, $numbers);

    foreach($numbers[0] as $match) {

        $number = str_replace($search,$replace,$match);
        $number = str_replace(' ', '', $number);
        $number = ' ' . $number . ' ';
        $subject = str_replace($match,$number,$subject);

    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Returns:

```
hello my name is inigo montoya you killed my father please call me at 8005551234 or 2057775111 prepare to die
```

With `str_replace()` "too" would need to be in `$search` before "to" or  you end up with "2o". Some word boundary honoring `preg_replace()`'s should clean it up.

Comment: Maybe something like this, https://eval.in/485791?

Comment: What do you mean by "non consecutive"?

Comment: The `$search` values may not be in the same order in `$subject` as they are in the array.

Comment: Yea, my example doesn't have them that way. Any word found in the haystack will be captured. What is the `$length` part?

Comment: in your example you seems like you want to get integer representation from string, but un your subject, the deal is to catch any non-consecutive string, can you be more clear that we can help you ? thanks

Comment: The `$length` is how many consecutive matches before considering it for the result.  In the example, once if finds 10 consecutive matches from `$search` in `$subject` it should add it to `$result`.

Comment: Basically, in the example, I'm trying to identify all worded phone numbers (10 consecutive words from `$search`) and then store them so I can go back afterwards and use `$result` to search/replace them actual digits.  The big problem is that there is no pattern and the `$subject` comes from speech recognition so I need a dictionary (`$search`) to capture things like 'to' or 'too'  for 'two', etc.

Comment: Oh, you mean the word numbers should all be consecutive.

Comment: Been there, tried that.  `str_replace()` doesn't respect word boundaries and I don't want "to" to be "2", etc.

Comment: How about https://eval.in/485813? Then `str_replace` your values because you know they are the phone number?

Comment: @chris85 thanks, working with this now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$subject = 'hello my name is inigo montoya you killed my father please call me '
         . 'at eight zero zero five five five one to three four prepare to die';

$search = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'to', 'too', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six',
           'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

$length = 10;

function jedi_find_trick($search, $subject, $length, $sep = ' ', $septype = 0) {
    // quote special characters in the search list
    $search = array_map(function ($i) { return preg_quote($i, '~'); }, $search);
    // quote the separator when it is a literal string
    if ($septype === 0) $sep = preg_quote($sep, '~');

    // build the pattern
    $altern = '(?:' . implode('|', $search) . ')';

    $format = '~(?:%1$s|\A)(%2$s'
            . ($length<2 ? '': '(?:%1$s%2$s){%3$d}')
            . ')(?=%1$s|\z)~';

    $pattern = sprintf($format, $sep, $altern, $length - 1);

    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
        return $matches[1];

    // return an empty array if there is no match
    return [];
}

print_r(jedi_find_trick($search, $subject, $length));
print_r(jedi_find_trick($search, $subject, 8, '\h+', 1));
```

By default, the separator is a space. When the septype is not 0, it means that the separator must be seen as a subpattern, (so no need to escape special characters).